# pubnub push notification titanium android

Tags: android, titanium, pubnub

I using pubnub chat for android using titanium appcelerator platform, I had  just crossed about the push notification to android via pubnub , It provides its own development kit for the chat clients but i tried to use it for android, I couldn't there is existing sample for ios but not for android actually.
Anybody had crossed this issue...let me know how to use this.

[Pub nub help link for push notification....](http://www.pubnub.com/how-it-works/mobile/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it is pretty simple as i thought to create a pubnub notification. We have to simply run background service and in that do the following steps.,

- Add background service using this **[BOOT_COMPLETED Titanium](http://bencoding.com/2013/04/02/using-boot_completed-in-titanium/)** module ,
- Before suscribe a new channel inside the background service code. (for eg.: **MY_notify_channel**),
- Next go to your chat screen , Next to the line that you are publishing to your private dynamic channel, Publish once again to our **MY_notify_channel** .
- That's it when ever you publishing you get a message received in your service box, you have segregate your message in that and then create a notification manually.
  [Titanium.Android.Notification link](https://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.Android.Notification)

Answer (score 3):

When using PubNub in an Android app (Phonegap or Native), you do not need to use GCM because you can implement a subscribe at boot service that forwards incoming messages to the background app using Intents. See this example for more details:
https://help.pubnub.com/entries/21720011­Can­my­Android­App­Receive­Messages­While­Inactive

That KB article has a link (hard to see in the article) that will lead you to the Subcrib-at-Boot example in the PubNub Andriod github repo here:
https://github.com/pubnub/java/tree/master/android/examples/SubscribeAtBoot­

**Android with Phonegap**
You need to implement a Phonegap JavaScript/Java bridge which has a bit of work that can be implemented by following our Android Subscribe­-at ­Boot (above) service solution and piece it together.
http://www.tipsfromsiliconvalley.com/2013/07/06/create­a­service­on­android­with­phonegap­ap plication/

Comment: It is also worth reading this answer on Quora:
http://www.quora.com/Does-PubNub-support-push-notifications-on-Android-as-they-do-on-iOS

Comment: This helps for native android developers..But i using titanium javascript to build android..i having confuse here how to code for service and receiver side also

Comment: Well, the point of the tipsfromsiliconvalley link is that you can do what you need to do, but you need a native written plugin to make it happen.